# NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL (Web Service)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have developed one Rest Web Service application in java and deployed the WAR file. While starting the server, the following error occurs.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have added following jar files to my project.

[image: added jar files]

I have downloaded jersey-common jar version 2.24.1.

I am not able to find where the actual issue is? Please help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your jersey-server.jar is `2.1` change it to `2.24.1`.
All Jersey dependencies should be in the same version.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I have corrected the version mismatches and the application is running successfully.